# Question related to the abelianization of simplectic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $H \subset \mathrm{Sp}(\mathbb{Z})$ be a subgroup of the simplectic group of (square of even dimension) matrices with integer entries, and let $H^{(\ell)}$ denote its pro-$\ell$ completion for some prime $\ell$. Then does $H$ being Zariski dense in $\mathrm{Sp}(\mathbb{Z})$ imply that the abelianization $(H^{(\ell)})^{ab}$ is finite?

Or does the converse hold (i.e. $(H^{\ell})^{ab}$ is finite for some $\ell$ implies $H < \mathrm{Sp}(\mathbb{Z})$ is Zariski dense)?

I have no idea how to go about solving this, and half expect that there are easy counterexamples that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: The converse seems to be disproved by considering e.g. any finite subgroup of Sp$_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @Jeff: Could you please give some motivation for the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is related to an open problem about finiteness of the index of an "arithmetic" group in its Zariski closure (see, for example, Peter Sarnak's lecture [*Thin Groups and the Affine Sieve*](http://publications.ias.edu/sarnak/paper/509) as well as [arXiv:math/0605675](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605675) and [arXiv:0803.3322](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3322)).